# Adobe Experience Manager 6.1 AEM 6.1 AEM 6.2 customize page content

Tags: java, aem, osgi-bundle, sling, htl

I want to create a page template might be used in multiple sites.

what I am currently doing is like this

```
<header class="">
<template data-sly-template.header data-sly-resource="${@path='header', resourceType='sitename/components/content/header'}" </div>
```

I need to dynamically pass the path so when user navigate to a different site same header should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass values to a template as shown below

```
<template data-sly-template.header="${@ path}">
    <sly data-sly-resource="${path @ resourceType='sitename/components/content/header'}"></sly>
</template>
```

and then call the header as shown below

```
<sly data-sly-call="${header @ path='header'}"></sly>
```